# What does "barely" imply?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, adverbs

When someone says,

> I barely understand that.

Does he mean:

> 1. He almost doesn't understand [which means he understands a bit]
> 2. He almost understands [which means he doesn't understand]

Or if someone says:

> Your brain is barely used.

Does he mean:

> 1. Your brain is almost not used [which means, it is used, but very rarely]
> 2. Your brain is almost used [which means it isn't]

I used to think that it was the first option. But a friend, out of the blue, said it was the second one.

Which one is it? Or have my friend and I got it entirely wrong?

Are there other words with similar meanings to *barely*? Is *nearly* one of them?

Comment: You are correct. Synonyms for barely are *hardly* and *scarcely*. A good discussion of hardly/scarcely(barely) [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hardly).

Comment: You've got it right.  'Nearly' is definitely not a synonym: it means "almost but not quite" whereas barely means "by the smallest margin".

Comment: @jbeldock: there are no exact synonyms. 'nearly' and 'barely' _are_ synonyms, just with nuances in different directions.

Comment: I think that's right, MItch.  I suppose I should have said "Nearly is less close in meaning".

Comment: So you guys mean like, if the sentences above used *nearly*, it would mean the second options? That *he almost understands (so he doesn't)* and *your brain's almost used (so it isn't)*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is item 1 in your post in each case which is correct.

It would be used to stress the fact of 'how little'. E.g., 'How can I possibly agree to marry him, I barely know him !'

Comment: Does this also reflect the accurate usage of *"barely"* with a quantity? I created a separate question with more details here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332753/what-does-barely-imply-when-used-with-a-quantity